# How to embed a php/javascript photogallery in a page of an html/css website?

Tags: php, javascript, css, embed

I have downloaded a freeware photo gallery called Minishowcase (freeware http://minishowcase.net/?main) to use in my website. The gallery works fine as its own site, but I can't figure out how to embed it in a page of my own site, which is largely css. I think I just need a line or two of code to incorporate the gallery, but I'm new to php and javascript.

Minishowcase is a folder containing a php index file and multiple folders (cache, config, galleries, libraries, etc.)

Can anyone tell me how to embed the whole photo gallery into a page of my website?

Thanks!

Comment: the best thing about the resource you have here is that it gives you all the files and folders. it just asks you to do a simple test which ive told you to do as well, this just checks whether php will work on your website. and if it does you're good to go. you will just need to follow the instructions which mainly include readjusting the page colour and content how you want the page to be displayed. its a simple text file where you change settings eg: black to blue. then shift over the folder into a directory into your webspace. link your page to gallery page. simple. have a look at my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, this is pretty simple. 
first check to see if PHP is installed on the server your site is located in. a simple question to the admin would do the trick. to be honest most servers that host have php installed. then to check if php really works where your website is located, create a file info.php inside it to make sure php is installed incase the admin take long time to reply back to you.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> PHP Test Script </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
phpinfo( );
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Afterwards, open your browser and type in the address to view that page. Something like... http://www.yourdomain.com/info.php

phpinfo is one of the "built-in" functions that PHP does. There are many others, but this one is a nice one to use to start of as a test.

Ok this being done. then you simply follow the installation instructions given to you by minishowcase. Dont worry its not as hard as it seems. php is a very friendly programming language which is why many people use it. so just give it a go. if you need help setting minishowcase up even after having a go at following the instructions then just give me a shout.

Although you have enough information here to get on with it :D

If you need any more help do let me know.

**PK**

Comment: Okay, I performed the test, and PHP is installed on the server for my site.

Comment: I followed the instructions for installing Minishowcase, and I end up with sort of a separate site: http://www.mydomain.com/minishowcase.

Comment: thats great news. now download minishowcase and follow the instructions. keep it short and simple when following the instructions. dont worry too much about how many files and folders are supplied with the cool gallery resource. just do as it is told

Comment: It doesn't look anything like the other pages in my site, and it's not accessible from my menu. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: what do you mean you end up with a different site? dont worry ill help you till this gets sorted :P

Comment: I'm making some progress. When I had tried to add header and footer information before I didn't attach the style sheet. Thanks for encouraging me to look at this again.

Comment: One thing I haven't been able to figure out is what page in minishowcase to link to in my menu.

Comment: hey stephanie im just relaxing looking at the post making sure everythings working well for you. then i look at your comment so im assuming you're giving me an update which is great. Let me know when youve done it so you can mark this post as answered so other people can use this as a reference to look at. until then you can ask me if you run into any more problems or queries you have in making this minishowcase gallery work with your site.

Comment: For example, other items in my menu are:<li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
<li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>      I tried this for minishowcase:
<li><a href="minishowcase/index.php">Photos</a></li>    And it's not the right link.

Comment: say if you have that code in a webpage called menupage.htm is there a folder in that directory called minishowcase ? and in that folder is there a file called index.php ? if your answer is not to any of those two questions then your link directory is written wrong and you need to specify the correct file path so that your webpage can locate the file and then open the file correctly.

Comment: Yes, there's a folder in my directory called minishowcase, and a file in that folder called index.php. In that same folder are located the files add_footer.php, and add_header.php to which I added my footer and header script.

Comment: right ok i see. ive downlaoded the folder as well. im looking through it and will get back to you straight away. just downloading an editor to view the files lol

Comment: The add_footer.php and add_header.php files preview successfully, but the index.php file is just a bunch of orange text and boxes, and I understand I'm not supposed to edit this file. Is it possible that the index.php doesn't preview, and to see it I must make the page live?

Comment: ok can i view this page please so i can have a look at it. thanks

Comment: It's not live. I tested that my server has PHP using another of my sites.

Comment: .. i see. ok well now you just need to upload the images directly. its tryin gto view images which you havent put up there most likely. you need to put images in a folder and put that folder in the galleries folder. dont quote me just read those instructions again as long as fotter and header are laoding properly its only a metter of time before index does as well. you just need to load the images into the directory in the right place and correctly as well. dont just put them anywhere anyhow .

Comment: My photo galleries were set up properly. When I preview index.php all that appears is the text you're not supposed to see because it's between backslashes:  /*
 * minishowcase : the super-easy gallery
 * by victor zambrano <minishowcase@frwrd.net>
etc.

Comment: I didn't copy my css into their file; I just linked the add_footer.php and header.php to my existing style sheet. This wouldn't have anything to do with, would it?

Comment: dont add anything to your own code specially when you are going to integrate css into it. i just want you to do this on a blank page. for example test everything from a fresh perspective before adding to your code.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. All my remaining issues had to do with sorting out the css conflicts between the two style sheets. Cheers.

Comment: ok thats awesome. wickid. so then the instructions that me and you tried did all work, it was just the fact that your css conflicted with their css so you just had to sort that out. nice one

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find anything else just put it in an iframe and remove the border from the iframe so it integrates with your page.

Comment: this is not the way to go about adding php content into a page especially if its from a simple feature like a gallery. all he has to do is add php code to his webpage which are given to him in the instructions file by minishowcase (the gallery) and then it will work providing he has php installed. Adding an iframe will be pointless if all he needs to do is add some php code to his existing file.

Comment: Well, Stephanie (a she, if I'm not mistaking) doesn't seem to know very much about PHP. I suggested a very simple solution if she finds it difficult to add the gallery to the PHP scripts.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use php for image galleries.

If it is not database driven

Try javascript or jquery image galleries.

They show you how to implement it.

Chek these

http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/jquery-image-galleries-sliders-best-of/